# Office 365 my site: some apps are not present

Tags: office-365, my-site

I would like to understand why the immediate mysite does not contain apps such as custom list, tasks, calendar and I am forced to create a team site as a subsite to have those items. Or is it only on my platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These features are not enabled by default. My suspicion is they are trying to separate the SharePoint components from OneDrive for Business and moving them off to Delve and other workloads.

They can be enabled though. You need to click on the gear when you are on `/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx` and click Site Settings. Click on manage site features and enable `Team Collaboration Lists` and you should be set.